# Getting Active Running Network Interface on Android

Tags: android

I want to know which of the Network Interfaces on my Android device is currently the active one Specifically I am interested in knowing which interface is currently "running" and not just "up".

In order to achieve this, I am trying to read the flags set for each network interface by reading the "flags" file for each interface located at:

```
/sys/class/net/*interface*/flags
```

Using OS monitor I see the following flags set for wlan0:

[image: OS Monitor information for Wlan0 Network Interface]

Reading the contents of /sys/class/net/wlan0/flags I get the following:

```
0x1003 => 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0011
```

According to the [Global definitions for the INET interface module](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/if.h) in order to match the information given by OS Monitor the flags should be set like this:

```
0000 0000 0001 0000 0100 0011 => 0x1043
```

In other words: The running flag is missing! :(

Why are not all the flags set?

Now I do believe that OS Monitor uses JNI and IOCTL to somehow fetch their information, but I was hoping to avoid using JNI.

Can any of you help me figure out how I can get this kind of information for each interface?

PS: Running ipconfig wlan0 also shows the flag "running".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found another approach.

I simply use the following code to go through all files and call ifconfig with their filenames and parse the result.

```
public static String getRunningInterfaceName(){    
    File folder = new File("/sys/class/net/");
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        // Open all "flags" files in subdirs, and ignore tun interfaces.
        if(files[i].isDirectory() && !files[i].getName().contains("tun")){
            try {
                String[] commands = {"ifconfig", files[i].getName()};
                Process ifconfig = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(ifconfig.getInputStream()));

                ifconfig.waitFor();

                String s = null;
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(!s.contains("loopback") && s.contains("running")){
                        stdInput.close();
                        return files[i].getName();
                    }
                }
                stdInput.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```